# Autocomplete within subroutine in perl IntelliJ via Camelcade / Perl5-IDEA pluging

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, camelcade

I have a problem with autocomplete when I define a subroutine with input parameter of type MIME:Entity.

From the perspective of the subroutine it is a reference. How can I make the IDE to understand that this input parameter is of type MIME:Enity and provide me with autocomplete ?

```
sub subWithNoAutocompleteOnEnity
{
        my ($entity) = @_;
        my $test = MIME::Entity;
        bless $entity, $test;
        if ($entity->parts(0)) {
           print("Say hello")
        }

}

my $parser = MIME::Parser->new;
my $entity = $parser->parse_open("$inputDirectory/$filename");
subWithNoAutocompleteOnEnity($entity)
```

Comment: *"..when I define a subroutine with input paramenter of type MIME:Entity"* : Note that you are missing a colon in the package resolution operator. It should be MIME::Entity (with double colon).

Comment: Can you also show a screenshot of the script you are editing within IntelliJ, demonstrating that autocomplete does not work?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have added sample code. In the main body of the file I have no problems with autocomplete. The question is how to make the IDE to recognise that $entity inside sub subWithNoAutocompleteOnEnity is actualy of type MIME::Entity

Comment: @HåkonHægland I thought that bless is some form of casting but it does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lexical variable can be declared with a TYPE attribute, see https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my, you can use this to help the Perl plugin to know what type the variable is, and how to autocomplete. Example:

```
use MIME::Entity;

sub subWithNoAutocompleteOnEntity
{
    # Using the type MIME::Entity to help the Perl plugin to autocomplete
    my MIME::Entity $entity = shift;
    if ($entity->parts(0)) {
        print("Say hello")
    }

}
```